# This loop terminates even though the condition is still met.

Tags: c++, loops

Hello this is my second question for the same c++ program (sorry if this is a simple issue)

I am trying to use a loop to check if a input was valid.  However this loop doesn't seem to respect if the input was valid or not.

```
int b(-1);
check = false;
while (b < 1 || b > 12)
{
    if (check)
        std::cout<<"Sorry try again!\nMonth: ";
    std::cin>>b;
    check = true;
{
```

If the user inputs a value between 1 and 12.  Otherwise continue with the loop.

However when I run the program and input a non-valid input it continues on.

```
Year: 2017
Month *In number format*: 20
Day:
```

Even -1 doesn't work and that is weird because I set the value as -1 before the loop starts.

```
Year: 2017
Month *In number format*: -1
Day:
```

Is it the use of the or statement with less than and greater than?

Comment: Please provide the full code snippet

Comment: sorry I incorrectly put the wrong curly brace.

Comment: correct it by updating your question again..

Comment: @amgtree please don't edit the question to include the solution in it. And worst to edit the issue out of the problem. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: @amgtree you should put a little more effort by yourself in solving your issues rather than resorting to outside help for each `;` or `}` you forgot or missuses. That's a friendly advice.

Comment: Again I apologize for this.  Also I edited because I thought the other user wanted me to do it.  Sorry if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter invalid input, stream's fail bit will be set. In this case, target variable (`b`) is not modified and as long as you do not clear the bit, each subsequent call of `operator>>` will fail, too, no matter what input you provide. Actually, the input is not taken from the stream at all, so you would re-read it again and again.

You should check the state of `std::in`, if need be clear the error bits and discard the invalid input:

```
if(std::in.fail())
{
    std::in.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```